# Python: How to display a big wndow with custom content, no widgets and no event loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface

I want to teach my kid, how to quickly read by syllables. For that I intend to write a program, that sequentially shows syllables on a screen waits for a microphone input to record, how the syllables ware pronounced. Later I would check if the recorded voice corresponds to the syllables.

I know how to detect and record a spoken word in Python. My problem is different and I believe very simple: how make a non-modal big window with custom text inside?

I know the question must sound very stupid for anyone having even a moderate experience in Python, but this will be my first try at UI for a looong time (I did some on VB6 a while ago) and I have exactly no experience how to do it, and I want to do it the easy and dirty way. I don't need a fancy UI with menus, widgets and stuff. Just a big blank window with a custom text and no controls and no event loop.

---

I am looking for something like that:

```
whdl=ShowWindow(text,fontsize)
#do my stuff    
Close(whdl)
```

Comment: Look at `tkinter`. It's the "builtin" python GUI toolkit. You should be able to find plenty of beginner tutorials around.

Comment: Did you do any research of your own yet? What did you find? What confused you about what you found?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes. Maybe the best way is to make some custom bitmap and show it with the picture viewer? But I guess there are simpler ways.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Whenever I search I find a whole GUI stuff with widgets and all. But what I want is very simple: just present a static window, and then hide it. No user interaction needed.

Comment: That is still 'real GUI stuff'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters allright then. I just thought there would be a simple function `whdl=ShowWindow(text,fontsize)`, and then `Close(whdl)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script that shows one way to do this, using [pygame](http://pygame.org/news.html).  The script shows several "words" in sequence, but you can hack away to make it do whatever you like.  (If you do, I suspect that eventually you'll want to use the usual GUI event loop, so you can handle key presses, mouse clicks, etc.)

```
import os
import time
import pygame


# Center the Frame in the screen.
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'

BG_COLOR = (224, 255, 255)
TEXT_COLOR = (0, 0, 255)
SIZE = (800, 360)


def show_window(text, font, screen):
    rendered_text = font.render(text, True, TEXT_COLOR)
    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    screen.blit(rendered_text, ((SIZE[0] - rendered_text.get_width()) // 2,
                                (SIZE[1] - rendered_text.get_height()) // 2))
    pygame.display.flip()


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 200)

words = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
for word in words:
    show_window(word, font, screen)
    # Replace the following `sleep` call with your stuff.
    time.sleep(3)

pygame.quit()
print "done"
```

Comment: Wow! Do you know that I started out doing more or less the same in the same framework, pygame!! I was just about to self-reply with my poor Python patchwork. Too bad, I've lost 4 hours on this, but at least I've learned a bit about PyDev on Eclipse. P.S. Your solution is much cleaner and simpler then mine.